# How to convert a panda series of 1-D numpy array to 2D numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
a = np.zeros((100,6), dtype=np.int8)
a_np_list = [arr for arr in a]
ser = pd.Series(a_np_list)
```

if I convert the series with ser.values, it is not with shape (100,6) but (100,), how to convert can result to a (100,6) 2D array?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
a = np.array(ser.tolist())
```